# Change focus to parent element using NightwatchJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

It is possible to move deeper into the DOM tree using the .frame JSON Wire Protocol call but I haven't been able to figure out a way to move upward through the DOM tree.

```
    module.exports = {
        "Enter and exit iframes in tree" : function(browser){
            browser
                //Currently focus is at top level.
                .frame('iframeOne')
                //Focus is now enters inner frame iframeTwo
                .frame('iframeTwo')

                //Attempt to move to frame directly
                .frame('iframeOne')
                //Selenium Error 'no such frame'

                //Attempt to move focus up to iframeOne by searching from root.
                .element('id', 'iframeOne', function(e){
                    browser.frame(e.value);
                }
                //Selenium Error 'no such element'

    }
```

There is a JSON Wire Protocol call frame/parent that is able to move up to the parent element but it is not currently supported by NightWatchJS. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In current binary releases, you need to use the `switchToDefaultContent` command. In Java this manifests itself as `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`. This will take you to the top of the frame hierarchy, and you can navigate back down the tree to the frame you need.

The "navigate to parent frame" wire protocol is brand new. On the order of days, at the time of this writing. No released server implementation at the time of this writing exists that understands that wire protocol endpoint. The Firefox driver has had it implemented only in the last day or so. Work hasn't started yet on the IE driver. It's not yet implemented in any language binding except Java, and that's only in the source tree; it hasn't been released in a binary form yet. If you're patient, it will be available to you in the future (no available timeline so don't ask), just not yet.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this would work if I were using the native Node.js | WebdriverJS code. The NightwatchJS framework doesn't currently support the switchTo() call.

Comment: In point of fact, `.frame(null)` is the equivalent of `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`. Why, oh why must the JavaScript development community suffer from Not Invented Here Syndrome and proliferate a vast number of JavaScript language bindings when perfectly good bindings already exist? I know of at least a half dozen independent JavaScript bindings for WebDriver. That's a rhetorical question by the way; the PHP community appears to suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this problem by resetting the focus back up to the top level element and crawling down again.

```
    .frame(null)
    .frame('iframeOne')
```

It's a workable solution.

Comment: This is exactly what my answer says to do, when it mentions using a command to "take you to the top of the frame hierarchy."